# How do I build for Mac Catalyst / x86_64-apple-ios-macabi?

Tags: rust, mac-catalyst, rustup

The output of `rustup target list --toolchain nightly` does not contain `x86_64-apple-ios-macabi`, even though it is in `src/librustc_target` on [the Rust master branch](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a0d40f8bdfcc3c28355467973f97fd4c45ac5876/src/librustc_target/spec/x86_64_apple_ios_macabi.rs).

How do I build for Mac Catalyst / `x86_64-apple-ios-macabi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x86_64-apple-ios-macabi` target is available on the nightly (5c5b8afd8 2019-11-16) compiler. Just because a target is available does not mean that the standard library and friends are compiled or available to rustup:

```
% rustc +nightly --print target-list | grep macabi
x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
```

Rust has a [tier system](https://forge.rust-lang.org/release/platform-support.html) (which is the subject of [a proposed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2803)). This target is so new it's not even listed on the tier list, but it's undoubtedly going to be tier 3. Tier 2.5 says (emphasis mine):

> Tier 2.5 platforms can be thought of as "guaranteed to build", but **without builds available through rustup**

In the meantime, you will need to build your own libcore / libstd from source.  I don't have the time nor ability to actually test that the compilation works, but something like these choices are the general starting path:

#### build-std

The unstable [`-Z build-std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#build-std) flag can be used to build the standard library:

```
% cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
```

#### Xargo

Building the standard library can be done using the [xargo](https://github.com/japaric/xargo) tool.

```
% rustup override set nightly
info: using existing install for 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'
info: override toolchain for '/private/tmp/example' set to 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'

  nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.41.0-nightly (5c5b8afd8 2019-11-16)

% cat > Xargo.toml
[target.x86_64-apple-ios-macabi.dependencies.std]
# features = ["jemalloc"] # Whatever is appropriate

% xargo build --target x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
# Iterate until libcore and libstd compile and work for your platform
```

Comment: Note you no longer need `xargo`. The new new-ish `-Z build-std` is enough for normal `cargo` to access any of the targets that aren't pre-built: `cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target x86_64-apple-ios-macabi`.

Answer (score 3):

Shepmaster's answer is a little outdated. Cargo now supports the `-Zbuild-std` command. Using it, you can target any of the targets that `rustc` itself supports even if they aren't listed on `rustup +nightly target list`. Simply:

```
rustc +nightly --print target-list
```

and

```
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
```

should be enough now. You don't need `xargo` to build the standard lib anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[@shepmaster 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917341/1457385) is correct. In detail, you have to:

- Install Xargo:

```
cargo install xargo
```

- cd in your project
- use the nighly build:

```
rustup override set nightly
```

- create the `Xargo.toml` file with content:

```
[target.x86_64-apple-ios-macabi.dependencies.std]
```

- In your projects Cargo.toml, make sure the `[profile.release]` section contains `panic = "abort"`. If it does not, add it.
- When building the project, use `xargo`instead of `cargo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old installation of rust, you might need to remove old nightly (or at least for me it fails to update nightly):

```
rustup toolchain remove nightly
rustup update
rustup toolchain install nightly
```