# How to build a Rust program for riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo, riscv, musl

I'm trying to cross-compile a Rust program for the tier 3 platform `riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl`, but am running into problems, I believe either with linking or with instructing Cargo properly.

I've tried just running:

```bash
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl
```

as indicated by [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916615/how-do-i-build-for-mac-catalyst-x86-64-apple-ios-macabi/58917341#58917341) and [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352828/how-to-build-for-tier-3-target-not-included-in-rustup-target-list), leading to a large log of errors:

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/open_computers_lib-0a95fe466728767f.1n96vpe9sdkbhvag.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/open_computers_lib-0a95fe466728767f.1n96vpe9sdkbhvag.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 243)
...
```

(redacting a longer list of that last line being repeated with different file names)

I've also tried using a pre-built cross-compiling toolchain from [here](http://musl.cc/) as well as trying to build the toolchain myself from [here](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain), and then using the following script:

```bash
export PATH="/opt/riscv-musl/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/:$PATH"
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl # same as before
```

Which gives me (same error log for both the pre-built and personally built toolchains):

```
   Compiling compiler_builtins v0.1.82
   Compiling core v0.0.0 (/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core)
   Compiling libc v0.2.135
   Compiling cc v1.0.73
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling std v0.0.0 (/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcL7qcAR/symbols.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.build_script_build.731b8ff0-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73.1qnaa8r4se7kx3js.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-f30f0c72643db558.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-f568c570fff954b1.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-e7b70edde5e55443.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-e89379089032cd0e.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-e7d90005a619f6ea.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-e8fa7b53a3149a70.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-db4d651637ed1365.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-255c18ca7ff0a7c6.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-1791beb5b36e409b.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-ab2b83cf39766489.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-21993ed5a33c1bb3.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b113a1d1429de7b6.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-0aacf29316aaa95c.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-fcf994c37af81dc5.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-a5319eed00c3264d.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-c6c03e024a2f1e46.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-522518611024dce5.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-05898138a596088a.rlib" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-b7c79d85cf21a511.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/lindon/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/lindon/Projects/Rust/open_computers_lib/target/debug/build/std-c8bbb31701f1fb73/build_script_build-c8bbb31701f1fb73" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /opt/riscv-musl/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_x86_64
          Supported emulations: elf64lriscv elf64lriscv_lp64f elf64lriscv_lp64 elf32lriscv elf32lriscv_ilp32f elf32lriscv_ilp32 elf64briscv elf64briscv_lp64f elf64briscv_lp64 elf32briscv elf32briscv_ilp32f elf32briscv_ilp32
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `std` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
...
```

The presence of `nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` in the path for `std` leads me to believe I could be instructing Cargo incorrectly, or it could just be because my host system is `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` .

## Additional information of possible importance:

- The program in question just has an empty `main` function.
- All testing was done after running performing a full system upgrade and running `rustup update` , and I am using 2021 edition of Rust in the project.
- I am running Arch Linux.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the right `ld` but telling it to link the wrong target `elf_x86_64`. That wall of parameters being passed to `cc` may be relevant after all.

Comment: @Caesar I added the `cc` parameter wall back in

Comment: Ah. If I interpret the output correctly, it's trying to build a `build.rs`, which needs to run on your machine, but it's trying to use the `riscv64gc` cc. Unsurprisingly, that fails. I'm not sure what the correct countermeasure is, maybe taking `riscv-musl` off the `PATH` and instead setting `[target.riscv64-unknown-linux-musl] linker = "…/ld"` and friends in `~/.cargo/config.toml`.

Comment: Ah, turns out that the `PATH` I was prepending doesn't have a `cc` in it, so I assume it was just calling my standard `cc`. Pointing it to a path with the actual `ld` I need gives me `riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory`, (among some other `crt*.o` files) and adding a `LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the folder doesn't change the outcome. I'm going to keep looking for a solution to that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prerequisites/Assumptions

This answer assumes the following:

- You are running Linux
- You have a `riscv linux musl` C cross-toolchain installed at `/opt/riscv-musl/`.

  - If you do not already have one, you will need to grab one from either your package manager, [download and extract it from here](http://musl.cc/), or [build it yourself from here](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain).
  - If it is not installed at `/opt/riscv-musl/`, simply replace that path in these instructions with the location the toolchain is installed to.
- You have Rust nightly installed.

  - If you do not, run `rustup toolchain install nightly`

## Instructions

With a Rust project folder structure like so:

```
├── src/
├── .cargo/
│   └── config.toml
└── compile.sh
```

Inside `config.toml`:

```ini
[target.riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "target-feature=-crt-static"
]
linker = "riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc"
ar = "riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-ar"
```

Inside `compile.sh`:

```bash
export PATH="/opt/riscv-musl/bin/:$PATH"
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std --target riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl
```

If `riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc` and `riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-ar` are already on your `$PATH` then the `export` statement in `compile.sh` is unnecessary.

Now if you want to compile to the `riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl` target, just run `compile.sh`.

## Additional Information

In order to get to the functional `config.toml` I ended up with, I took the following:

```ini
[target.riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl]
rustflags = [
"-L/home/blackdragon2447/x-tools/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/sysroot/lib",
"-L/home/blackdragon2447/x-tools/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/11.2.0/",
"-L/home/blackdragon2447/x-tools/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/riscv64-unknown-linux-musl/sysroot/usr/lib",
"-C", "link-args=-lc",
"-C", "prefer-dynamic",
"-C", "target-feature=-crt-static"
]
ar = "riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-ar"
linker = "riscv64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc"
```

from [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93975) and trimmed it down, so if the one in this answer doesn't work for some reason, try playing around with that one (don't forget to change the paths in it).